# LibreELEC: Fix date

Tags: pi-3, kodi, timekeeping

Using LibreELEC v7.0.2 with Kodi 16.1 on a Raspberry Pi 3.

The date and time is incorrect. It can temporarily be fixed by SSH'ing and running `date --set` with a provided date. But on boot, the date resets to the date when Kodi was compiled: June 22 2016.

As far as I can tell, there is no option to fix the date in Kodi. The most you can do via its UI is to choose your region and timezone.

Tried SSH'ing and having the datetime synced via ntpd but it's not possible to configure a list of servers in a `/etc/ntp.conf` file as the file system is read-only.

How can you set the correct date on LibreELEC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured out how to set the correct date and time from within Kodi.

1. Go to "LibreELEC Settings"

   - From the main menu: Programs -> Add-ons -> LibreELEC Configuration
2. Go to the "Network" tab
3. Add some time servers under the "NTP Servers" section

   - Find servers best for your region at http://www.pool.ntp.org
   - Or just use pool.ntp.org as your single time server
4. Set "Wait for network before starting Kodi" under the "Advanced Network Settings" section

   - The default "Maximum Wait Time" will be 10 seconds

Answer (score 7):

`Settings` > `Interface` > `Regional` > `Timezone country` ( > `Timezone`)

Comment: Note for UK users: Timezone country is 'Britain (UK)' which I missed the first time and was confused, expected it to be under 'UK' or 'Great Britain'.

Answer (score 2):

Settings > Interface > Regional > Timezone country
once the country is set, you should see the word Timezone change from being grayedout to white. then click on Timezone > your area.

For me it's Timezone Country > United States, Timezone > America/Bosie, since I live in Idaho.

Answer (score 0):

got to Settings/interface, this is where it gets tricky. go to the bottom next to the settings cog and hit enter till it goes to expert then go to regional and change timezone country then do regular time zone

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, ensure you're router allows NTP requests. When I had FreshTomato set to intercept NTP client requests the time wouldn't refresh in LibreElec